# Finding total number of days worked

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

31-dec 2015 - admissiondate for each person and add all those days to get the total number of days worked in sql.

For example only 2 person a and b  during 2015 jan to 31 dec period then -a spend 5 days,b spend 10 days then you want the answer to be 15 
tried as below

```
select count(DATEDIFF (d,'2015-12-31' , admittedon) from  admission
where   (admittedon BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-31') or 
      (DischargedOn BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-31')
```

Comment: @kaisquared it's valid MSSQL, don't know about postgre

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking so that we know which SQL dialect it is since date time functions vary between them.

Comment: Your question is pretty unintelligible. Can you explain what is wrong with the SQL that you tried?

Comment: If datedifference is 5 for 1 and
9 for another then i want total count to be 14.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this is what you want:

```
select count(DATEDIFF (d,'2015-12-31' , admittedon) + 
       count(DATEDIFF (d,'2015-12-31' , DischargedOn) as days 
from  admission
where   (admittedon BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-31') or 
        (DischargedOn BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-31')
```

you just need to count the Dischargedon part and plus them together.